# Where is my Tkinter Canvas image?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I have some issues with displaying a canvas image within a separate class.

I have a top level application and another top level class representing a sort of panel with a smaller image of the main windows canvas for navigational purposes.

I know that I have to keep a reference to my canvas image in order for it to be safe from the garbage collection, however, I fail to achieve the desired result.

The code for the panel class is as follows:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class MultiPanel(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self,parent,cookie):
        Toplevel.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.transient(self.parent)
        self.attributes('-topmost',True)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self._NULL)
        self.visible=[BooleanVar()] * 2
        for i in range(0,1): self.visible[i].set(True)
        filename=cookie['basename']+os.sep+cookie['current_file']
        self.PANEL=PanedWindow(self,orient=VERTICAL)
        self.PANEL.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

        self.nFrame=Frame(self.PANEL)
        self.Navi=NaviPanel(self.nFrame, imgpth=filename)
        self.image=self.Navi.image
        self.Navi.pack()

        self.bFrame=Frame(self.nFrame)
        bToggle=Checkbutton(self.bFrame,text='Info panel', variable=self.visible[1],onvalue=True,offvalue=False,command=lambda i=0:self.toggle_vis(index=i))
        bToggle.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.bFrame.pack(side=RIGHT)

        self.bottom=[]
        self.bottom.append(Frame(self.PANEL))
        l=Label(self.bottom[0], text="bottom pane").pack()

        self.PANEL.add(self.nFrame)
        self.PANEL.add(self.bottom[0])

    def _NULL(self):
        pass

    def toggle_vis(self,index):
        if not self.visible[index+1].get(): self.PANEL.forget(self.PANEL.panes()[index+1])
        else: self.PANEL.add(self.bottom[index])

class NaviPanel(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,imgpth):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(os.path.normpath(imgpth)))
        self.parent=parent
        self.canvas=Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image=self.image,anchor="ne")

    def redraw(self,x,y,cextent,pImage,scale,col,fname):
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image=pImage,anchor="nw",tags=("bg",0)) #in the panel
        self.canvas.configure(width=x,height=y)
        self.filename_label.configure(text=fname)
        rect = [int(float(i)/scale) for i in cextent] #rectangle coordinates
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(rect,outline=col,tags=("view",0)) #in the panel

    def moveview(self,x,y,cextent,scale,col):
        self.canvas.delete('view') #destroy rectangle
        rect = [int(float(i)/scale) for i in cextent] #rectangle coordinates
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(rect,outline=col,tags=("view",0)) #in the panel

    def hide(self):
        self.withdraw()

    def show(self):
        self.deiconify()

    def toggle(self,Event=None):
        self.visible = not self.visible
        if self.visible:
            self.hide()
        else:
            self.show()

    def _NULL(self):
        pass
```

In my main application, I'm creating the window by

```
        self.panel=MultiPanel(self,cookie=self.cookie,ptitle=PTITLE)
        self.pImage=self.panel.image
```

I have tried all manners of referencing the actual image from the main application down to the canvas `frame` element, as well as referencing the whole canvas from the main application.

Where is my mistake?

PS: Sorry for the long post!

Answer (score 0):

I am deeply sorry, but the error was in the wrong anchor options that I've used for the canvas image. Replacing it by anchor='nw' solved everything. It was very confusing to see a behaviour that so closely resembles the problem with not referencing the image, so I kind of got lost!